# Foreach looping too many times

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

I'm using this to display information from a queried db in Wordpress.  It displays the correct information but it loops it too many times.  It is set to display from a SELECT query and depending on the last entry to the db seems to be whether or not it prints double or triple each entry.

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
echo '<h5><i>'.$row->company.'</i> can perform your window installation for <i>$'.$row->cost.'</i><br>';
echo 'This price includes using<i> '.$row->material.'</i> as your material(s)<br>';
echo '<hr></h5>';
}
```

Does anyone know what could be producing this error?
Thanks

The query powering that script is:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT bp.*, b.company 
FROM `windows_brands_products` bp 
LEFT JOIN `windows_brands` b 
ON bp.brand_id = b.id 
JOIN Windows_last_submissions ls
JOIN windows_materials wm
JOIN Windows_submissions ws 
WHERE ws.username = '$current_user->user_login'
AND bp.width = ROUND(ls.width) 
AND bp.height = ROUND(ls.height) 
AND bp.material IN (wm.name) 
AND bp.type = ls.type 
AND IF (ls.minimumbid != '0.00',bp.cost BETWEEN ls.minimumbid AND ls.maximumbid,bp.cost <= ls.maximumbid)
ORDER BY b.company ASC");
```

I can't seem to see the duplicate but I agree it must be there.
EDIT-- when I replace the WHERE clause to WHERE ws.username = 'password' , it still repeats.  It it displaying a result for each time a result has username='password' , and displaying that set twice as well.

Comment: Can you show us your query and relevant parts of the database schema? My guess is that you might have some duplicate rows in your query perhaps from a join. `foreach` is not the problem here, I can guarantee that.

Comment: Too vague, need a bit more info. Also don't think you can use `foreach()` on result object. Would look at `fetch_assoc()` like functions for your `$result`, like: `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ }`

Comment: @Twisty - $result is probably simply an array of objects, that's perfectly valid and can be iterated just like any other array - additionally, objects that implement `Iterable` can be iterated using a `foreach()`, as can `Generators`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include examples of DB entries that trigger double or triple entries (or single if there are any). Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: @MarkBaker I would agree if OP had not mentioned performing a `SELECT`. This suggests a db result object and not an array of objects. Plus OP does not define what SQL functions he is using. I am not arguing your point, I agree with it, yet I am making suggestions based on the context of the post and tags.

Comment: @MarkBaker - I also stand informed: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php _Iterator support was added, as mysqli_result now implements Traversable._ So I guess it's just not common practice, since it would iterate Prop. and Methods, right? Not the data set?

Comment: Thanks all for responding!  Here is the query I currently have powering that script

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you run the SQL Query manually?

Comment: Using while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {} gives me a non-object error.  So the function to run the query is: $result = $wpdb->get_results( " " )

Comment: Good question Twisty.  It does repeat the results I'm trying to troubleshoot it now but no luck yet.

Comment: So it sounds like an issue in your SQL Query. IS that what you're saying, you have duplicates when you perform the query manually?

Comment: Yes Twisty.  Seems to be looping once through rows WHERE username='username' , and displays those loops twice so it appear ROW1 ROW1 ROW2 ROW2

Comment: I assume you do not have multiple users by the same name? Also why use tables `windows_materials` and `Windows_submissions` in your query if they are not apart of the WHERE or SELECT?

Comment: Also some of your JOIN statements seem ambiguous, they have no relationship to the primary table.

Comment: I do need windows_materials actually but You're right about the other one.    Windows_last_submissions is a view from Windows_submissions with a LIMIT 1 clause, so by taking Windows_submissions out and replacing its pertaining WHERE clause and replace with ls.username  everything seems to work fine now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the following, if you're using MySQLi:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
     echo '<h5><i>'.$row->company.'</i> can perform your window installation for <i>$'.$row->cost.'</i><br>';
     echo 'This price includes using<i> '.$row->material.'</i> as your material(s)<br>';
     echo '<hr></h5>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Redundant JOIN clauses in my query which was pretty much pulling the same results from two tables (one of which was just a VIEW of the other).